# April 2015 Windows 8.1 Update: winload.efi error 0xc000000f

Tags: windows-8, boot, windows-8.1, bootloader

I have an Acer V3-772g: Intel i7 4712MQ, NVIDIA 750m 4 GB

I installed the newest Windows 8.1 updates a couple days ago; however, the update failed. I left the computer to update and then went to work, so I wasn't able to see where the computer left off and all.

When I went to reboot, I got a blue screen error. I don't remember the boot error for that HDD. Luckily, I had a backup disk with the Acer OEM Windows 8.1. 
I had thought I disabled Windows Update, but it had already installed. I went to reinstall Visual Studio 2013, and it said I needed to restart my PC first. I didn't think anything about it and preceded to restart my computer.

When I came back the computer had completely shut off and didn't do the complete reboot, so I turned the computer on.

Now I get error code `0xc000000f`

> The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
>   `C:\Windows\system32\winload.efi`

It then gives me the option to boot up into the startup settings, try again, or boot into the UEFI settings.

When I boot into the recovery flash drive and access the terminal, I can run `bootrec /scanos` and my Windows 8.1 install is located. However when I run the `/fixboot` command, it says the system could not find the file specified.

**Update**: `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` both return `The system cannot find the file specified.` However, `bootrec /scanos` returns `total identified Windows installations: 1` and tells me it's on the D: drive.

1. Has anyone else had this issue with the April Windows update?
2. What is the best method to proceed with fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

I somehow looked over the different options for `bootrec.exe`.
I was able to do `bcdboot D:\windows`

`D:\Windows\` is the location of the Windows folder on the drive.
When booting from a recovery disk to as follows:

1. `bootrec /scanos` //hopefully this will show the drive letter of the OS installation
2. `bootrec /fixmbr`
3. `bootrec /fixboot` //note that these two commands did not work for me. I received an error that said the system can't find the file specified. I believe the update deleted the files these two commands edit.f
4. `bcdboot {path_to_Windows_folder}` // this should have shown in the first step

I hope this fixes the `0xc000000f` problem others may receive because of the Windows update.